# Data restructure using PIVOT and UNPIVOT in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, bigdata, unpivot

I have a table with the data similar to the original data.
By using the original data, i want to restructure to the modified data like in the table using PIVOT or UNPIVOT in SQL.

Original Data

| lot | table1 | table2 | table3 | table4 | ... | table28 | headno | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | xxa | xxb | xxc | xxd | ... | xxf | 1 | … |
| b | xxg | xxe | xxi | xxp | ... | xxx | 1 | … |
| c | xxk | xxm | xxr | xxt | ... | xxu | 4 | … |
| … | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | … | … |

result after modification

| lot | table | table NO | head no | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | xxa | table1 | 1 | … |
| a | xxb | table2 | 1 | … |
| a | xxc | table3 | 1 | … |
| a | xxd | table4 | 1 | … |
| a | ... | …. | … | … |
| b | xxg | table1 | 1 | … |
| b | xxe | table2 | 1 | … |
| b | xxi | table3 | 1 | … |
| b | xxp | table4 | 1 | … |
| b | ... | … | … | … |
| c | xxk | table1 | 4 | … |
| … | … | … | … | … |

Thanks in advance.

[Original data and Modified data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ystl3.png)

[Original data and Modified data Updated version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bisbv.png)

Comment: Please check the image attached and update.

Comment: Yes! the background and text color are both back. So could not see anything

Comment: can you please check the updated version?

Comment: Yeah, This is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My technique to unpivot is to abide by a general SQL standard (one that is not limited to running on a specific database).

Un-pivoting, in that case, is about CROSS JOIN-ing the 'horizontal' table with an in-line table `i` consisting of the integer column `i` and of as many consecutive integers as there are horizontal columns to pivot - and a CASE WHEN expression to use the right column depending on the current value of `i` in the current result set:

```
WITH
-- your input - 5 columns work the same as 28 ...
-- do not use in your real query.
indata(lot,table1,table2,table3,table4,table5,headno) AS (
          SELECT 'a','xxa','xxb','xxc','xxd','xxf',1 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'b','xxg','xxe','xxi','xxp','xxx',1 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'c','xxk','xxm','xxr','xxt','xxu',4 FROM dual
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
-- need series of integers - 28 rather than 5 in the full example ..
i(i) AS (
          SELECT 1  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5  FROM dual
)
SELECT
  lot 
, CASE i 
    WHEN 1 THEN table1 
    WHEN 2 THEN table2 
    WHEN 3 THEN table3 
    WHEN 4 THEN table4 
    WHEN 5 THEN table5 
    ELSE NULL
   END AS tbl 
,  'table'||CAST(i AS VARCHAR(1)) AS table_NO
, headno
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i 
ORDER BY lot,i
-- out  lot | tbl | table_NO | headno 
-- out -----+-----+----------+--------
-- out  a   | xxa | table1   |      1
-- out  a   | xxb | table2   |      1
-- out  a   | xxc | table3   |      1
-- out  a   | xxd | table4   |      1
-- out  a   | xxf | table5   |      1
-- out  b   | xxg | table1   |      1
-- out  b   | xxe | table2   |      1
-- out  b   | xxi | table3   |      1
-- out  b   | xxp | table4   |      1
-- out  b   | xxx | table5   |      1
-- out  c   | xxk | table1   |      4
-- out  c   | xxm | table2   |      4
-- out  c   | xxr | table3   |      4
-- out  c   | xxt | table4   |      4
-- out  c   | xxu | table5   |      4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a big data and the values in table is more than 10000. In that case what can i do?

Comment: Your "technique" is to use the same name for a view and for its column? Brilliant!

Comment: Do you mean that you have over 10,000 columns in the input table? It should still work, as far as I'm concerned. You might want to create 100 rows in the `i(i)` table, and CROSS JOIN it with itself to create 10,000 out of 100, before CROSS JOIN-ing it with the base table

Comment: I mean, is there any other methods for this statement 
SELECT 'a','xxa','xxb','xxc','xxd','xxf',1

because i also have other data to apply in it.

Comment: I just added an in-line full select: `WITH in data( ... ) AS SELECT(...)` to have example data in my example. You should work without that part; the real query starts after the `indata` common table expression. I commented the query accordingly just now. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you so much @marcothesane. It worked perfectly. 

I have one different question about joining columns from two different schemas and cross joining them. There is one common column with same data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT lot,
       "TABLE",
       tableno,
       headno
       /*,...*/
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  "TABLE" FOR tableno IN (
    table1, table2, table3, table4, /*...,*/ table28
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (lot, table1, table2, table3, table4, /*...,*/ table28, headno /*,...*/ ) AS
SELECT 'a', 'xxa', 'xxb', 'xxc', 'xxd', /*...,*/ 'xxf', 1 /*,...*/ FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'xxg', 'xxe', 'xxi', 'xxp', /*...,*/ 'xxx', 1 /*,...*/ FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'xxk', 'xxm', 'xxr', 'xxt', /*...,*/ 'xxu', 4 /*,...*/ FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | LOT | TABLE | TABLENO | HEADNO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | xxa | TABLE1 | 1 |
> | a | xxb | TABLE2 | 1 |
> | a | xxc | TABLE3 | 1 |
> | a | xxd | TABLE4 | 1 |
> | a | xxf | TABLE28 | 1 |
> | b | xxg | TABLE1 | 1 |
> | b | xxe | TABLE2 | 1 |
> | b | xxi | TABLE3 | 1 |
> | b | xxp | TABLE4 | 1 |
> | b | xxx | TABLE28 | 1 |
> | c | xxk | TABLE1 | 4 |
> | c | xxm | TABLE2 | 4 |
> | c | xxr | TABLE3 | 4 |
> | c | xxt | TABLE4 | 4 |
> | c | xxu | TABLE28 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=33385e8924f7ad8d0f6bd7ce4bedfa83)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a big data and the values in table is more than 10000. In that case what can i do?

Comment: @William 10,000 rows is a relatively small number. It should work fine.

Comment: I mean is there any another method for this statement SELECT 'a', 'xxa', 'xxb', 'xxc', 'xxd', /*...,*/ 'xxf', 1 /*,...*/

Comment: @William That is just creating the table with the test data; you should already have it in your schema in whatever table you created.